# How can I convert JSON to DataTable using C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a json string and would like to make a DataTable from it.

How can I convert JSON to a DataTable in C#?

**Update:**

I have used Json.Net as per link provided here

and build 2 class to to handle json string as per below

```
 public class JsonHelper
        {
            public List<User> userdata { get; set; }
        }

  public class User
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }

    }
```

and use following code to Deserialize

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer json = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();

            json.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            json.ObjectCreationHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;
            json.MissingMemberHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
            json.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

            StringReader sr = new StringReader(jsonstr);
            Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
            object result = json.Deserialize(reader, typeof( JsonHelper));
            reader.Close();

            return result;
```

but getting following error

> Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 'mynamespace+JsonHelper'.

What should be problem here , please help me to sort out this problem.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer) by Rick Strahl may help you out.  Under the covers he's using Newtonsoft's JSON.NET libraries to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: I have tried to use this but getting error please see my updated question.